# Redirect TLD (dev) to local IIS

Tags: iis, dns

In the office, we have already setup a redirect in the DNS to push .dev back to the localhost.  The issue is when I am not in the office this does not work.  I edited my host file for the websites but as I add more in the future I would prefer to not have to edit my host file.

Is there a way, within my computer, that I can force the TLD of .dev to always go back to my localhost?

I realize I may have to find a way to do this on my router so that the DNS is resolved.

Example:

```
- Local IIS
-- Website A (with a Host Name Binding of website-a.dev)
-- Website B (with a Host Name Binding of website-b.dev)
```

When I open a browser on my local box and type in website-a.dev, it should loop back to my local IIS and pull this website. Same thing for website-b.dev, of course, going to the other website.  Now I know if at work we have setup the DNS to allow for this but I want to know if this can be done at home, where I do not have direct access to the DNS.

I know I can just put into my host file

> 127.0.0.1 website-a.dev

But I want a catch all for .Dev to go back to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

https://superuser.com/questions/135595/using-wildcards-in-names-in-windows-hosts-file

It explains that using Acrylic allows you to use wildcards and acts just like your host file.

Comment: I have used the URL Rewrite Module for IIS with Umbraco before and this really does not solve the issue I am looking at.  I will edit my question and provide an example.

Comment: I updated my answer - based on the additional information you provided.